# I want some help of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $1.$ Let $u$ and $v$ be orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|u\|=2$ and $\|v\|=3.$ Find $\|2u+3v\|.$

I do it like $\|2u+3v\| < 2\|u\|+3\|v\| = 2.2 + 3.3 = 13$.

> $2.$ Let $u$ and $v$ be orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|u+v\|=1$ and $\|u-v\|=5.$ Find  $a)\;\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$ and $b) \;u\cdot v.$

a) I do it like this we know this basic property $\|u+v\|^2 + \|u-v\|^2 = 2(\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2)$, then $1 + 25 = 2(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2) = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 = 13.$

b) Since $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal $u\cdot v = 0$.

Is what I do correct?

Comment: You've shown your work, but asked no question. What is it that you expect as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In question $1$, you wrote $\|2u+3v\| < 2\|u\| + 3\|v\|$. I don't know how you did that. In general, we have the triangle inequality $\|a+b\| \leq \|a\| + \|b\|$ and homogeneity $\|\lambda a\| = |\lambda|\|a\|$, but if you apply those you get $\|2u+3v\| \leq 2\|u\| + 3\|v\|$. Even if you do this, all you obtain is an upper bound for $\|2u+3v\|$ rather than its exact value. What you need is an equation which relates $\|a+b\|$, $\|a\|$, and $\|b\|$ in the case where $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal. Do you know of such an equation? (Hint: right angled triangles).

**Added Later:** I've just realised that question $2$ doesn't make any sense. If $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal vectors, then $\|u + v\| = \|u - v\|$. This leads me to believe that this question should not include the hypothesis that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal. If this is the case, your working for part $(a)$ is correct, but your working for part $(b)$ is no longer correct.